# Full image not being downloaded

Tags: php, php-7.1

I am currently building a carousel which has team images inside. The images for each employee are able to be called from an api, so rather than calling it every time, i have a separate file that calls and stores the images locally once a day.

Now my issue is, that about 1 in 10 images aren't fully transferred, and are cut off. I need the full image.

Here is what I am currently doing to call and store them:

```
$url = 'https://demo.mageewp.com/jasmine/wp-content/uploads/sites/54/2013/03/image-alignment-150x150.jpg';
$img_url = 'assets/images/headshots/' . $photo_name;
file_put_contents($img_url, file_get_contents($url, false, $ctx));
```

I've tried using curl, and that returned with about every 1 in 2 images not being returned fully.

It is random also, on one loop, image 2 is fine for example, and if i run it again it is not!

Comment: What is `$ctx`? And what file sizes are we talking about?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware $ctx is this: 
 $ctx = stream_context_create(array('https'=>
        [
            'timeout' => 99999,
        ]
    ));

and they are a few kb in size

Comment: In what way is this executed (in a loop or separate instance per download) ? is it always the same files that fail? does php have enough memory? (I assume the storage location has enough space)

Comment: Going to guess the requesting server is failing.  Is it resizing the images on the fly or something similar?

Comment: I have just tried to call all the images at the same time in seperate tabs using the api url, and they all displayed fine, so it's not the api having the issue.

@HTDutchy They are in a loop of the amount of employees, with each iteration, it saves their details and then moves onto the next person. The images are all 150x150 and are less than 5kB in size! and yeah the storage location has a few hundred GB left.

Comment: @KieranRigby Really long shot... perhaps the server/api is blocking site crawlers? try putting a `sleep(rand(2,4))` in the loop temporarily.

Comment: @HTDutchy No luck unfortunately :(